# Is there a way to send a note when deleting an event in the Google Calendar v3 API?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

In the Google Calendar web interface it's possible to send a note when cancelling (deleting) an event, like so:

[image: Google Calendar event cancellation UI]

Is this also possible via the v3 Google Calendar API? I looked at the Event delete API docs (and others), but there doesn't seem to be a parameter or option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to DaImTo it is [not currently possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996619/is-there-a-way-to-send-a-note-when-deleting-an-event-in-the-google-calendar-v3-a#comment118432907_66999401) to set the note text when sending notifications about cancelled events.

If you'd like to see this feature implemented, [star this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153711338).

Answer (score 0):

If you check the documentation for [events.delete](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/delete) you will find that there is an optional parameter for sending updates to the user upon deletion

[image]

Comment: Hi DalmTo, the question is whether or not you can include the **note text** via the API when calling `event.delete`. Unless I'm misunderstanding the call it seems like the `sendUpdates` string specifies who should receive the delete notification.

Comment: When the event is deleted the user will be notified.  However you can not pick the message that is sent to the.   I am just telling you what is possible in the limitations of the API as it currently stands. As what you want to do is not possible, and you have an interesting idea i encourage you to send a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B).